# How do I place my search field to my desired position

Tags: django, materialize

I want to place the search field to the location I like, I need it to be displayed at the center as it can be seen in the picture below I have tried to use class="right" and class="center-align" both are not working, and actually it is not at the center, little more to left. Please help!!

base.html

```
    <ul class="center-align">
      <li>
        <form action="{% url 'loststuffapp:IndexView' %}" method="get">
          <input name="q" type="text" placeholder="Search..." value=" 
           {{request.GET.q}}">
        </form>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

[image: Navbar image]

Answer (score 1):

You should add "margin-left" and "padding-left" to the search field in CSS.

```
input {
    margin-left: 50px;
    padding-left: 50px;
}
```